# Problem making changes in synaptic package manager

Tags: package-management, synaptic

I am listed as administrator in settings, but when I go to synaptic package manager via terminal I get message "Starting "Synaptic Package Manager" without administrative privileges

You will not be able to apply any changes, but you can still export the marked changes or create a download script for them."

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it with `pkexec` explicitly

```
pkexec synaptic
```

or use the provided wrapper

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

(which appears to be how the desktop launcher does it).